# convert one dimensional array to multidimesional

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi I have following array list I need to convert it to something as follow group it by company and show categories as second array.

```
 [0] => Array
  (
    [company_id] => 1
    [avatar] => '092EF7DB-B478-2EF5-1CC5-4A46D285B5F0.jpg'
    [comp_name] => Hotel 1
    [categories] => Array
    (
      [cat_+category_id] => Reception
      [cat_+category_id] => Accommodation
    )

[1] => Array
      (
        [company_id] => 8
        [avatar] => ''
        [comp_name] => Hotel 2
        [categories] => Array
        (
          [cat_+category_id] => Reception

        )
etc
```

original array below

```
0 => {#359 ▼
  +"category_id": 10
  +"company_id": 1
  +"cat": "Reception"
  +"comp_name": "Hotel 1"
  +"avatar": "092EF7DB-B478-2EF5-1CC5-4A46D285B5F0.jpg"
}
1 => {#354 ▼
  +"category_id": 12
  +"company_id": 1
  +"cat": "Accomodation"
  +"comp_name": "Hotel 1"
  +"avatar": "092EF7DB-B478-2EF5-1CC5-4A46D285B5F0.jpg"
}
2 => {#358 ▼
  +"category_id": 10
  +"company_id": 8
  +"cat": "Reception"
  +"comp_name": "Hotel 2"
  +"avatar": null
}
3 => {#361 ▼
  +"category_id": 10
  +"company_id": 23
  +"cat": "Reception"
  +"comp_name": "Hotel 3"
  +"avatar": null
}
4 => {#365 ▼
  +"category_id": 12
  +"company_id": 23
  +"cat": "Accomodation"
  +"comp_name": "Hotel 3"
  +"avatar": null
```

can you please advise how to achieve it in php 
thank you
Dany

Comment: do you want to sort array by `company_name`?

Comment: share your original array to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ (or similar) to get a quick help

Comment: here is the code in sandbox http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e65d60cf8c9a5f0aaa001000fbfc1eff2b337dd0

Comment: Hi Petro I have tried this `foreach($results as $company) {

            $arr[] = ['cat' => $company->name ];

            $data[$company->company_id] = [ 'comp_name' => $company->comp_name, 'avatar' => $company->avatar,  $arr];


        }` but that is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `$originalArr` is your original one-dimensional array, **the solution** to convert your one-dimensional array to multi-dimensional array would be like this:

```
$resultArr = array();
foreach($originalArr as $arr){
    if(!isset($resultArr[$arr['company_id']])){
        $resultArr[$arr['company_id']] = array('company_id' => $arr['company_id'], 
                                            'avatar' => $arr['avatar'],
                                            'comp_name' => $arr['comp_name'],
                                            'categories' => array('cat_' . $arr['category_id'] => $arr['cat'])
                                        );
    }else{
        $resultArr[$arr['company_id']]['categories']['cat_' . $arr['category_id']] = $arr['cat'];
    }
}
$resultArr = array_values($resultArr);

// display $resultArr array
var_dump($resultArr);
```

Comment: great this was working perfect exactly what I needed

Comment: @user1859876 Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)